# Pipe stream to response and cache

Tags: node.js, caching, express

I am making a simple proxy for images from Imgur. I have some basic code which checks to see if a file is in the cache, and if it is then it pipes it from the cache to the response, and if it isn't it pipes it to the cache:

```
if (fs.existsSync('cache/' + req.params.image)) {
  fs.createReadStream('cache/' + req.params.image).pipe(res);
}else{
  request(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('cache/' + req.params.image));
}
```

Now the issue is that when a new image is added in order to see it you have to load the page twice. Once to cache it, and then again to read from the cache. What I want to do is pipe it to the cache and the response at the same time. Is this possible, and how do I do it?

Comment: Cant you just listen to close even of write stream and send the response after that?

Comment: @neolivz4ever I'd prefer to do it asynchronously

Comment: Did you try https://www.npmjs.org/package/multiplex-stream